# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key “Id”

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello everyone i have a problème while creating , although i did the same thing with others same app & it worked can't understand why not in this one , i keep on getting this error message " There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key “Id" ;

Here's my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Filièreitem = (from f in db.Filières select new SelectListItem { Text = f.Name, Value = f.Id.ToString() }).ToArray();

        return View();

    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(String Id, String Name)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var Specialité = new Specialité()
            {
                Filière = db.Filières.Find(int.Parse(Id)),
                Name = Name
            };
            db.Specialités.Add(Specialité);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();

    }
```

And here's the Form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Specialité</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Filière.Id, "Nom Filière", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FilièreItem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Filière.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I really hope you guys can find what's the problem cause i need this project next Saturday.

Comment: Because you do not repopulate `ViewBag.FilièreItem` in the POST method before returning the view (as you did in the GET method) so its `null`. But there is  no point of checking `if (ModelState.IsValid)` - its always valid because you do not bind to a model, and why are you returning the view anyway - once you save the data, you redirect.

Comment: i didn't understand what you're trying to say can you please explain a little bit further ?

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: I got it now thank you sir , actually the problem was Return view() ; i totally forgot about it i have one more question if you may answer it ... how to prevent Multi registration using same adresse Email  .. & thank you ^^

Comment: There are multiple other problems with your code. Your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` are pointless - you do not even create a form control for `Filière.Id` and anyone can post back `null` for you `Name` property anyway. Use  a view model - it will contain properties `string Name`, `int `SelectedFilière` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FilièreList` and then you apply validation attributes to your properties, including a `[Remote]` attribute to check for unique email addresses.

Comment: Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx)

Comment: In the POST method, you have a parameter which is your view model, then you check is `ModelState` is valid, if so, map the properties of the view model to a new instance of the data model and save it, then redirect. If not, you return the view to display the validation errors so the user can correct them.